# dynamic value inside richtext editor

Tags: umbraco7

I am tring to use some data from my content to be shown in richtext editor.
but It shows as a text;

```
var contactDetails = @Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().ElementAt(2);

@contactDetails["Phone"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a macro for that and allow to use them in the rich text editor.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/